# KnockoutJS - managing multiple triggers

Tags: knockout.js

Whats the best way of managing multiple triggers in Knockout. The below dependent observable will fire the trigger when the number of travellers in the array changes or when the selected group type changes.

```
var ajaxTrigger = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    this.selectedGroupType();
    this.travellers();
    alert("triggered");
}, viewModel);
```

However I have a subscription on selectedGroupType that can change the number of travellers:

```
viewModel.selectedGroupType.subscribe(function(groupType) {
    switch(groupType)
    {
        case "Individual":
            // changes traveller quantity to 1
            break;
        case "Couple":
            // changes traveller quantity to 2
            break;
        case "Family":
            // changes traveller quantity to 3
            break;
        default:
            break;
    } 
}, viewModel);
```

So I'm in the position that if I make a change to selectedGroupType then its possible that I will get a second trigger if the traveller quantity changes.

However I just want one trigger call after both the grouptype and number of travellers has been decided.

Whats the best way round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at throttling. Take a look at item 6 on Steve Sanderson's blog:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/

```
// Will not notify changes faster than once per 500ms 
var myObservable = ko.observable("initial value").extend({ throttle: 500 });

// Will not re-evaluate *or* notify changes faster than once per 500ms 
var myDependentObservable = ko.dependentObservable(function() { 
    // Evaluation logic goes here, usually referencing other observables 
    return 123;
}).extend({ throttle: 500 });
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll download the latest version.

Comment: I tried adding a throttle of 1000ms and now the Ajax request is made once, as soon as the page renders and then again after 1 second. Its strange because the call to the Ajax request is made from a dependent observable and even if I remove all references to other observables the AJAX request is still fired: var ajaxTrigger = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            GetPrices();
        }).extend({ throttle: 1000 });

Comment: I know this is really old however to help anyone who happens upon this question, with ko.dependentObservables (now called ko.computed) they get evaluated when first binding to figure out what observables are in it. What I ended up doing in a very similar situation is have an initialized variable that is set to true at the bottom of the viewModel and in the ko.computed call the observables I want to bind to but check to make sure initialized is true before calling the ajax so I don't trigger the ajax call during initial evaluation.